# How can i make jQuery plugins compatible w/o changing the whole code?

Tags: jquery, plugins, compatibility

The regular way to keep jQuery compatible to other frameworks is to override the $-Function with the following code:

```
jQuery.noConflict();    
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery("someelement").dosomething();
    });
```

or

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();    
$j(document).ready(function() {
      $j("someelement").dosomething();
    });
```

but is there also a way to keep additional jquery-plugins compatible without changing the whole $-Function-Signs like above?

Thanks in advance!

Danny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `jQuery` object is passed as argument to the `ready` handler, so you can do:

```
jQuery.noConflict();    
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("someelement").dosomething();
});
```

Regarding plugins: They should only access the global `jQuery` element anyway, to exactly avoid these kinds of compatibility issues.

Most plugins are defined as

```
(function($) {
    // plugin code here
}(jQuery));
```

If they are not, then they are designed badly. If you have such a plugin, you should write the author of it to fix it. You'd have to change the source and wrap the whole code inside this function to make it work.